# Split data to respective topics using KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

This is source topic ->>

```
{
  "subscriber": {
    "mem_ID": "587994622344",
    "mem_PIN": "07066",
    "case_NUMBER": "21307P019",
    "mem_FIRST_NAME": "Henry",
    "mem_MIDDLE_NAME": "S",
    "mem_LAST_NAME": "Taylor",
    "mem_ADD_1": "1255",
    "mem_ADD_2": "New Street",
    "mem_CITY": "Clark,NJ"
  },
  "patient": {
    "pat_ID": "133235413144",
    "pat_SEX": "M",
    "pat_DOB": "198760321",
    "case_NUMBER": "21307P019",
    "pat_FIRST_NAME": "Olive",
    "pat_MIDDLE_NAME": "",
    "pat_LAST_NAME": "Taylor",
    "pat_PLANE_TYPE": "HealthCare",
    "pat_PLAN_NAME": "HC"
  },
  "case": {
    "CASE_NUMBER": "21307P019",
    "CASE_TYPE": "Medical",
    "CASE_CODE": "MC",
    "CASE_START_DATE": "20220723",
    "CASE_END_DATE": "20220831",
    "CASE_AUTH_TYPE": "Insurance",
    "CASE_STATUS": "Initiated"
  },
  "service": {
    "svc_ID": "134324564678",
    "case_NUMBER": "21307P019",
    "svc_TYPE": "Day Care",
    "svc_CODE": "DC",
    "svc_FAC_ID": "HC",
    "svc_FAC_NAME": "Heart Center",
    "svc_PHY_ID": "34343555",
    "svc_PHY_NAME": "Dr.Charles"
  }
}
```

how to split the above source topic to different 4 topics using KSQL. For e.g. >> Subscriber topic should have only Subscriber Data like this

```
{
  "mem_ID": "587994622344",
  "mem_PIN": "07066",
  "mem_MIDDLE_NAME": "S",
  "mem_LAST_NAME": "Taylor",
  "mem_CITY": "Clark,NJ",
  "mem_ADD_2": "New Street",
  "mem_ADD_1": "1255",
  "case_NUMBER": "21307P019",
  "mem_FIRST_NAME": "Henry"
}
```

Similarly the other 3 topics Patient, Case and Service

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you have some common schema in your source topic, do you store json messages or did you have multiple producers who simply serialized something like the content of a class `Subscriber` or a class `Patient` to the same Kafka topic?

Comment: We have array of such Json in source topic as shared above

Answer (score 1):

Create a Stream from your original data, then select those fields...

```
CREATE STREAM subscribers WITH(KAFKA_TOPIC="subscribers", VALUE_FORMAT="JSON") AS 
    SELECT subscriber.* FROM source_stream;
```

https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/create-stream-as-select/

Alternatively, start with 4 separate topics in your producer, and later join on the case number, for example

Comment: How to create a source stream from original data  i.e original topic? How to define its columns in streams as it have different objects like subscriber, patient and so on. Can you share query for creating source stream from original topic

Comment: You'd use CREATE STREAM and give each of the top level fields as a STRUCT type https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/sql/data-types/#struct  There are several examples and tutorials in the docs of handling JSON data